# Reactivity in depth in data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need some help. I have a component where I pass a prop and I need to assign a variable from my data to the prop variable, but in a reactive way. I cant modify the child it only accepts Booleans. The problem is that Vue initializates the data, but the disabled attribute isnt reactive. I know that if I pass an object to the disabled attribute that will be reactive, but I cant.

```
data() {
 let editmode = true;

 return {
  EditMode: editmode,
  schema: [
    {
     disabled: !editmode,
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

In the future I need to edit the value of EditMode and I want to that edit to be passed to my child component. I pass the schema variable to the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response! I think I havent described my problem enough. I understood that a variable isnt referencable only the objects. I post the answer I got in the Vue forum, in the hope I can help someone else, because this solved my problem. [Solution](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/reactivity-in-depth-in-data/47975/4?u=itpalert)

```
<template>
  <form-generator :schema="schema">
</template>

<script>
  Data() {
   return {
     EditMode: false,    
   },
   methods: {
     Edit() {
      this.EditMode = true.
     }
   },
   computed: {
     schema() {
       return [
         {
          type: "MInput",
          disabled: !this.EditMode,
         }
       ]
     }
   },
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute disabled is not reactive because he is not receiving a referenced variable to pass it reference across the data structure, basically you is saying disabled: !true, that evaluated to disabled: false, and "false" is just false, not a reference from the variable because a boolean is not referenceable, a object is (by example, and this is one of reasons to data hook return a object)! And if you change the editmode variable nothing is gona to happen ... Rethink your data structure and edit what your need putting these data in a object to be reactive! Hope it helps.

If you really need two separated variables, a workaround is use a watcher to detect when editMode changes and populate the changed value to another variable in data..

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="change">Change Edit Mode {{editMode}}</button>
        <child-component :isEditing="!schema.disabled"></child-component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        name: "test2",
        components: {

            'child-component': {

                template: "<div>Editing? {{isEditing}}</div>",
                props: {

                    isEditing: {

                        required: true,
                        type: Boolean
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        data(){

            return {

                editMode: true,
                schema: {

                    disabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {

            change(){

                this.editMode = !this.editMode;
            }
        },
        watch: {

            editMode(n){

                this.schema.disabled = !n;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```